# Is there a way to check the speed of the shiny applications

Tags: r, shiny

I have a very simple applications in my local. The same is been deployed on shiny server pro. But I see that there is difference in execution speed. The local one is vert fast, but the one deployed on shiny server is slow. Not sure why. Both are same code.

So wanted my client is asking if we can quantify the speed of the applications. Can we do this?

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sliderInput("x", "If x is", min = 1, max = 50, value = 30),
  sliderInput("y", "and y is", min = 1, max = 50, value = 5),
  "then, (x * y) is", textOutput("product"),
  "and, (x * y) + 5 is", textOutput("product_plus5"),
  "and (x * y) + 10 is", textOutput("product_plus10")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$product <- renderText({ 
    product <- input$x * input$y
    product
  })
  output$product_plus5 <- renderText({ 
    product <- input$x * input$y
    product + 5
  })
  output$product_plus10 <- renderText({ 
    product <- input$x * input$y
    product + 10
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Profvis package](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/profiling.html).  In your example there is not much to check, but you can run the app with provfis as `profvis::profvis(runApp(shinyApp(ui, server)))`:

```
library(shiny)


ui <- fluidPage(
  sliderInput("x", "If x is", min = 1, max = 50, value = 30),
  sliderInput("y", "and y is", min = 1, max = 50, value = 5),
  "then, (x * y) is", textOutput("product"),
  "and, (x * y) + 5 is", textOutput("product_plus5"),
  "and (x * y) + 10 is", textOutput("product_plus10")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$product <- renderText({ 
    product <- input$x * input$y
    product
  })
  output$product_plus5 <- renderText({ 
    product <- input$x * input$y
    product + 5
  })
  output$product_plus10 <- renderText({ 
    product <- input$x * input$y
    product + 10
  })
}
profvis::profvis(runApp(shinyApp(ui, server)))
```